# Solving trigonometric equations with two variables in fixed range?

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry

I am trying to use 'Solve' function to solve two trigonometric equations with two variables `a1` and `a2` (with range `0,2Pi`). I wrote the code in the following:

```
  Vets={Cos[2a1](I+Cos[2a2])+Sin[2a1]Sin[2a2], (I-Cos[2a2])Sin[2a1]+Cos[2a1]Sin[2a2]};
  Solve[Vets[[1]] == 1 && Vets[[2]] == 0 && 0<=a1<=2Pi && 0<=a2<=2Pi, {a1,a2}]
```

but it gives errors:

> Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.

I looked up the documents for `Solve` function and it should be no problem with the above code. But it doesn't do anything and give errors, I don't understand why?

It will be super cool if anyone could answer this question, thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Vets = {Cos[2 a1] (I + Cos[2 a2]) + Sin[2 a1] Sin[2 a2], 
    (I - Cos[2 a2]) Sin[2 a1] + Cos[2 a1] Sin[2 a2]};
```

The complex-valued solutions are periodic. You can set the arbitrary constants to specific values, e.g.,

```
sol0 = Solve[Vets[[1]] == 1 && Vets[[2]] == 0, {a1, a2}] /. 
   {C[1] -> 0, C[2] -> 0}

(* {{a1 -> 1/2 ArcTan[I/2, -(Sqrt[5]/2)], 
  a2 -> 1/2 ArcTan[2 I, -Sqrt[5]]}, {a1 -> 1/2 ArcTan[I/2, Sqrt[5]/2], 
  a2 -> 1/2 ArcTan[2 I, Sqrt[5]]}} *)

sol0n = sol0 // N

(* {{a1 -> -0.785398 + 0.240606 I, 
  a2 -> -0.785398 + 0.721818 I}, {a1 -> 0.785398 - 0.240606 I, 
  a2 -> 0.785398 - 0.721818 I}} *)
```

Or restrict the complex variables to a region

```
sol1 = Solve[
  Vets[[1]] == 1 && 
   Vets[[2]] == 0 && 0 < Abs[a1] < Pi/2 && 0 < Abs[a2] < Pi/2, {a1, 
   a2}, Method -> Reduce]

(* {{a1 -> -I ArcTanh[(1 + 2 I)/Sqrt[5]], 
  a2 -> -I ArcTanh[(2 + I)/Sqrt[5]]}, {a1 -> I ArcTanh[(1 + 2 I)/Sqrt[5]], 
  a2 -> I ArcTanh[(2 + I)/Sqrt[5]]}} *)

sol1n = sol1 // N

(* {{a1 -> 0.785398 - 0.240606 I, 
  a2 -> 0.785398 - 0.721818 I}, {a1 -> -0.785398 + 0.240606 I, 
  a2 -> -0.785398 + 0.721818 I}} *)
```

**EDIT:** These solutions are equivalent

```
Thread[({a1, a2} /. sol0[[1]]) - ({a1, a2} /. sol1[[2]])] // 
  ComplexExpand // FullSimplify

(* {0, 0} *)

Thread[({a1, a2} /. sol0[[2]]) - ({a1, a2} /. sol1[[1]])] // 
  ComplexExpand // FullSimplify

(* {0, 0} *)
```

Comment: wow, cool. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

This way Mma doesn't give a warning and states that there is no solution:

```
Vets = {Cos[2 a1] (I + Cos[2 a2]) + Sin[2 a1] Sin[2 a2], (I - Cos[2 a2]) Sin[2 a1] + 
    Cos[2 a1] Sin[2 a2]} // TrigToExp;
Solve[Vets[[1]] == 1 && Vets[[2]] == 0 && 0 <= a1 <= 2 Pi && 0 <= a2 <= 2 Pi, {a1, a2}]
```

If to remove the condition for `a1`, `a2`to be real,

```
 Vets = {Cos[2 a1] (I + Cos[2 a2]) + Sin[2 a1] Sin[2 a2], (I - Cos[2 a2]) Sin[2 a1] + 
        Cos[2 a1] Sin[2 a2]} // TrigToExp;
    Solve[Vets[[1]] == 1 && Vets[[2]] == 0, {a1, a2}]
```

it gives 4 series of complex solutions.

Comment: thank you for the answer. Is there any way to limit the range for the variables in a easy way?

Comment: I think the way you applied is very easy and I don't know any better for this case. In the documentation there is a way $\{x,y,\ldots\}\in reg$ specifying a region $reg$.

Comment: By the way |Vets|^2 is equal to 2 for real values of parameters: FullSimplify[Norm[Vets]^2, {a1, a2} \[Element] Reals], so the system indeed doesn't have such solutions.

Comment: well, you are right. let's take a simple case `Vets = {Cos[2a1] + Sin[2a2] , Sin[2a1] + Sin[2a2]}` (for sure we know the results easily but how can one restirct the range for `a1` and `a2` such that one doesn't get the periodic results?)

Comment: The way you used works: Solve[Vets[[1]] == 1 && Vets[[2]] == 0 && 0 <= a1 < Pi && 
  0 <= a2 < Pi, {a1, a2}]